# How can you procedurally dismember a character model?

Tags: unity, 3d, rendering, software-engineering, graphics-programming

For example in the new Doom, you can use a chain saw and slash an enemy apart, the enemy actually splits in half in the path of the chain saw. I know how to do the cheap effects where you store a copy of an already chopped up model and then when you kill the enemy it's replaced with the chopped up model. But the real good ones, like in Doom or Shadow Warrior, split depending on how you slash it. How do they do that? I've been searching this on google for the past year, and I haven't found many tutorials or articles on it. Please help!

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96LInqKNCHY

Comment: Part by part: particle effects, texture painting, etc... AAA companies will have the role "visual effects designer" to solve those problems. On "split depending on how you slash it" you could edit the mesh and use 3d textures. But that might be too expensive for most cases. Some games do have a large set of "chopped up model" that will require time to start to pick repeated ones.

Comment: This question has already been asked: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26712/how-to-program-a-cutting-tool-for-3d-model-in-game?rq=1
(And it also has an answer which will point you in the right direction) :)

Comment: By starting at index 0. Ambiguous questions warrant ambiguous answers.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe Doom uses a set of pre-build slicing animation for where the chainsaw hits the enemy. After that you can use some sort of mesh slicer to slice the target mesh according to the chainsaw impact. The blood spray could be made with a combination of a particle system and decals. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/879q457fs3m5dtm/AACVSTvDaVJQcmDwnXfzLA5Ha?dl=0) is a really good mesh slicing system for unity to get you started.

Comment: May you mention author and license of the linked package?

Comment: Package is from [this](http://blinded-am-me.tumblr.com/) tumblr site that I found from google.  Cant find any mention of a license on there SO I'm assuming that the code is provided as is meaning a MIT licence.

Comment: My understanding is that [no license defaults to exclusive copyright](https://choosealicense.com/no-license/), not MIT.

Comment: @Pikalek Thing is he has posted his work on gitHub so its public.